# Cordova FileTransfer: upload image to AWS s3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Am using `ng-cordova` [file-Transfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugin to upload images to my `AWS s3 bucket`.

but i run into two problems first it didn't work, second i have no idea how to debug the problem while the App running on the emulater.

here is my code:

```
.controller('newItemCtrl', function($scope, $http, API_URL, me, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
       var s3URI = encodeURI("https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/"),
                policyBase64 = "MY_BASE64_ENCODED_POLICY_FILE",
                signature = "MY_BASE64_ENCODED_SIGNATURE",
                awsKey = 'my AWSAccessKeyId',
                acl = "public-read";

        var options = {
            fileKey: "avatar",
            fileName: "image.png",
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "image/png"
    //        params = {
    //            "key": fileName,
    //            "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
    //            "acl": acl,
    //            "policy": policyBase64,
    //            "signature": signature,
    //            "Content-Type": "image/png"
    //        }
        };

        var imageURI = '../img/ionic.png';
        $scope.upload = function($cordovaFileTransfer) {

            $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(s3URI, imageURI, options)
                .then(function(result) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
                }, function(err) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                }, function(progress) {
                    // constant progress updates
                });
        }
})
```

I also left the params code to ask another question it's commented, but before i run my app and it gives me an error with the params but my question why i got the error even before invoke the template assosiated with that controller

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, to debug I used the live server logs to check and see if the file upload hit the server at all, some errors I noticed:

- my server was expecting a different file key
- the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header wasnt being sent properly in the server's response

Then, I also installed the cordova native notifications plugin (link [here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/use-native-device-dialogs-ionic-framework-mobile-apps/)) and sprinkled alerts throughout the file transfer callbacks to see where things were getting stuck

Anyway probably not the best way to debug, but it worked.

Hope that helps.

...one more thing the params part of "options" seems to work best when applied in this format:

```
    var options = {
        fileKey: "avatar",
        fileName: "image.jpg",
        /*params: {
          "value1":"value1",
          "value2": "value2"
        }*/
    };

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "value1";
    params.value2 = "value2";
    options.params = params;
```

from the cordova [docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) "params: A set of optional key/value pairs to pass in the HTTP request. (Object)" so passing in a dictionary may be subtly different, I'm not sure, all I know is that it worked once I made that change.

Comment: How do you access the "params" object on the server? Have tried for hours.. no success.

Comment: I often use webapp2 on google app engine, and there I access "params" as I would from a normal post, so something like: "self.request.get('param_name')". For the file object I've used self.request.POST['image'], where 'image' is what I used for the fileKey.

Comment: So basically you get them from the POST object, some logging of the entire http post might be needed to find the right syntax.

Comment: I was using the ngCordova implementation of the FileTransfer plugin. I tried everything and I couldn't get the params object. I then switched to the native FileTransfer plugin  and it worked. I could get the params using POST['field'] normally. Don't know if the wrapper is broked or I didn't use it correctly. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To debug on emulator I use this from my app directory: `ionic emulate ios -lc`

That shows me errors or logs into the console.